# How to read registry value correctly in C#

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey, getvalue

I have created a key of type string and named it `mykey` in registry at `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT` with the value set to `1234`.

I have a windows form application with a button on it.

I want to see the value of `mykey` in a MessageBox whenever the button is pressed. How can I achieve that?

This is what I did. But this code only shows `HKEY_USERS` in the MessageBox and not the value of `mykey`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegistryKey rk = Registry.Users;
        rk.GetValue("HKEY_USERS\\.DEFAULT\\mykey");

        if (rk == null)
            MessageBox.Show("null");
        else
            MessageBox.Show(rk.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Why is that a duplicate @PedroG.Dias

Comment: @PedroG.Dias How is that link even an answer?! I don't understand. My question is within the context, while the link you gave -- which links to another link, by the way -- is not. It doesn't even have one proper example.

Comment: Sorry, removing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified `User` two times but you have to do that anyone of that, here is the safe way to read registry value

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(".DEFAULT"))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                Object val = key.GetValue("mykey");
                if (val != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(val.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("Null");
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You specify the `Users` part twice. First as the hive of the registry and then as registry key.

You can remove it from the latter:

```
rk.GetValue(@".DEFAULT\mykey");
```

Or you should start with the registry without selecting a hive:

```
Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\mykey");
```